# What is the syntax to change link color in a span element?

Tags: html

I am trying to modify the link color inside a <span>.  (I know that this is not optimal/conforming, but I am stuck in a situation where I don't have access to the header and also cannot play with the `<a>` tags.)  I tried something like this, which doesn't work

```
<span style="a {color:#C04040} ">
Try to change in a &lt;span&gt;: <a href="http://nonesuch">This link</a>
</span>
```

I also tried other variations, like:

```
<span style="a.color:#C04040">
```

I admit that I don't understand the syntax of <style> as a tag, as opposed to inside the header.  Would appreciate any help, or links to complete documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: What header? Do you mean inside the `head` element? Style elements can be used anywhere.

Comment: The style _attribute_ accepts properties and values, not selectors. A style _element_ accepts selectors with associated properties and values in a brace block. There are plenty of tutorials out there which address this.

Comment: Anchor tags, are a special case, in that they have "pseudo" states, and you can not set the properties of those pseudo states inline for an anchor tag, and you certainly can't set them in a parent element.  It actually makes no sense why you would be able to change the markup of your code, yet, unable to change the page header, but let's assume that there's some hurdles in your way you are trying to work around, perhaps because there's a template in place.  You should look for existing .css files being included and change those.

Comment: If it's some sort of cms, that will let you add static html blocks, you could also get around it by have a <style></style> in the page that sets the anchor pseudo states the way you want them, but you are in the process making an invalid html page, even though it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply this rule to all your span tags, you can just place this in the content of your html document. Then all tags inside a span tag will get red with blue background.

```
<style> 
span a { color:red; background-color:blue; }
</style>
```

If you want to apply this only to a specific span tag, just use a named class like

```
<style> 
span.colorlink a { color:red; background-color:blue; }
</style>
```

And then you can do <span class='colorlink> for the spans you want colored.

Comment: Right, but I always thought that a style tag should be placed in the header. But then I checked the w3c standard and there are no such requirement. So I rewrote my answer

Comment: Should, if only for good document organization. In more than 20 years of development it's never been a problem for me. You see it _everywhere_, especially on CMS sites. And _head_, not header. Headers are something else. Documents have heads and bodies. :)